# Unresolve Dependencies Spark library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I followed this link :  http://blog.miz.space/tutorial/2016/08/30/how-to-integrate-spark-intellij-idea-and-scala-install-setup-ubuntu-windows-mac/

When I try to compile my project with Intellij, sbt is complaining about unresolved dependencies

> [Warn] ===public: tried [Warn]
>   https://repol.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core/2.1.1/spark-core-2.1.1.pom
>   [Warn] Unresolved dependencies path: org.apache.spark:spark-core:2.1.1

My scala version is 2.12.2 and sparkVersion is 2.1.1

Here is what my build.sbt look like :

```
name := "test" version := "1.0" scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

`val sparkVersion = "2.1.1"`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" & sparkVersion)`
```

thank you

Comment: You must use Scala 2.10.x or 2.11.x as scala 2.12 is not supported by spark yet

Comment: Spark community is working on scala 2.12 support.Please follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your last line should be

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion
```

Or

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10"  % sparkVersion)
```

And its better not to use `scalaVersion := "2.12.2"` as mentioned by @Nonontb and @Cyrelle. Please reduce the version that `spark` supports for better performance and to avoid unexpected errors.

the following line is from [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/)

> > For the Scala API, Spark 2.1.1 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

Comment: Actually, since OP uses scala 2.12, they should use `"spark-core_2.12"`, or better yet use `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion` to fetch automatically the relevant jar for the given scala version.